# Calculate the division of 2 numbers and show the recurring pattern in Java

Tags: java, decimal, division

Thanks for the thumbs down.

I want 2 numbers divided and I want to print the number with total accuracy.

After the decimal pattern occurred I want a comma and to indicate the length of the recurring pattern.

Comment: Hi.  Can you show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: @rayryeng I guess your comment is proof people do not look at the answers.

Comment: This was flagged as low quality. I didn't "bother" looking at the answer because it wasn't obvious to me that you were trying to answer your own question. I looked at the question, it looked like a "give me teh coodz" scenario and commented accordingly. I apologize as it isn't my fault as I'm not a mind reader.

Comment: @rayryeng The funny part to me is not how you didn't read my answer but how 3 people thumbs upped your comment. Now I feel fully comfortable to ignore the opinions of the comments. One of the reasons I asked this question is because someone stole it for homework and thought they could delete their own question to avoid plagiarism, also because I thought it was pretty cool little method and I would maybe like to see another way to do it. I noticed there wasn't just some code to do it on google so I decided to throw it in here for people to see.

Comment: Fair enough. Have fun.

Answer (score 1):

One way you can solve this is by doing long division sort of like this, what you want to do is solve your problem like you would long division on a piece of paper.

```
static void codeCamperDivison(long n, long d) {
    long r; // remainder
    long g; // goes into
    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
    ArrayList<Long> rh = new ArrayList<Long>(); // remainder history
    ArrayList<Long> gh = new ArrayList<Long>(); // goes into history
    for (long i = 0;; i++) {
        r = n % d;
        g = n / d;
        s.append(g);
        if (i == 0) // whole number portion
            s.append(".");
        if (r == 0) { // non-recurring number
            s.append(0);
            break;
        }
        gh.add(g);
        if (rh.contains(r)) { // recurring pattern found
            s.append(",");
            List<Long> pattern = gh.subList(rh.lastIndexOf(r) + 1, gh.size());
            for (long l : pattern)
                s.append(l);
            s.append("...");
            if (pattern.size() == 1)
                s.append("\nrecurring length=infinite");
            else
                s.append("\nrecurring length=" + pattern.size());
            break;
        }
        rh.add(r);
        n = r * 10; // add a 0 like in long division
    }
    System.out.println(s.toString()); // print results
}
```

Comment: Could you please [edit] your answer to give an explanation of why this code answers the question? Code-only answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272), because they don't teach the solution.

Comment: @DavidPostill thought the code comments would be enough, I'll try again.

Comment: @DavidPostill because then I will not see the recurring patterns. Once a recurring pattern is reached I can repeat it once after the comma and put an elipsis to indicate it infinitely repeats. Can you do that with BigDecimal? Really I am just interested in seeing other ways to accomplish this as I made this code myself. This is more like a fun little educational calculator method.